# How do I use rake:db:prepare with mssqlserver?

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby

I am trying to set up Rails tests with MS SQL server. Currently Rails is working just fine with the normal development environment environment on the same SQL server instance.

I initially tried by manually creating a database with the same login as I used for development attached to it called PRODUCT_TEST. Database created fine.

when I ran rake db:test:prepare I got this

```
C:\Code\git.product>rake db:test:prepare
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::JDBCError: CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.: CREATE DATABASE PRODUCT_TEST
```

so it looks like it drops and recreates the DB.

I added the user to all of the roles of the DB server and tries again and got this.

```
C:\Code\git.product>rake db:test:prepare --trace
** Invoke db:test:prepare (first_time)
** Invoke db:abort_if_pending_migrations (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:abort_if_pending_migrations
** Execute db:test:prepare
** Invoke db:test:load (first_time)
** Invoke db:test:purge (first_time)
** Invoke environment
** Execute db:test:purge
rake aborted!
The driver encountered an unknown error: Cannot open database "PRODUCT_TEST" requested by the login. The login failed.
C:/Program Files/jruby-1.7.0.preview1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-e49ec53fb369/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/connection.rb:91:in `initialize'
C:/Program Files/jruby-1.7.0.preview1/lib/ruby/gems/shared/bundler/gems/activerecord-jdbc-adapter-e49ec53fb369/lib/arjdbc/jdbc/adapter.rb:33:in `initialize'
```

The database no longer exists and has been dropped. I tried this with both the user I created and the 'sa' user and neither work. I am able to connect to the database server and my development database using either just fine, both in enterprise manager and rails.

The database.yml looks like this

```
test:
  adapter: jdbcmssql
  username: sa
  password: password
  host: 127.0.0.1
  database: PRODUCT_TEST
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Note: using Rails 3.2.3, JRuby 1.7.0.preview, Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition (64-bit) 10.50.1617.0

Comment: Fixed: I recreated the PRODUCT_TEST database manually and and assigned the account as the owner. This time the tool did not drop the database and was able to access it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed: I recreated the PRODUCT_TEST database manually and and assigned the account as the owner. This time the tool did not drop the database and was able to access it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found that setting the default database to 'master' resolved the problem.

Security > Logins > *click on login* > Default Database: master